# Как из массив перевести в строку без запятых

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки

```js
    text = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!'];
    console.log(text.toString()); // H,e,l,l,o,!
```

Как сделать, чтобы при переводе в строку не было этих запятых?

Answer (score 4):

Через `join()`:

```js
var text = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!'];

console.log(text.join(''));
```

При этом в качестве параметра `join()` передается строка, которая будет вставляться между символами исходного массива.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var text = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!'];
var result = text.reduce((res, item) => res + item, '');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: А чем этот вариант отличается от решения, предложенного @wcobalt 'ом? Какие особенности, отличия, как работает?))

Comment: @Pon4iPay Ключевые слова для поиска: javascript, array, reduce.